# Transition animation not working in SwiftUI LazyVStack

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm currently working on an Expense Tracker app using SwiftUI, and I'm trying to apply a transition animation to a LazyVStack that displays a list of expenses fetched from Core Data using @FetchRequest. However, the animation doesn't seem to be working as expected. Here's a simplified version of the relevant code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ExpenseView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
    
    @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [SortDescriptor(\.date,order: .reverse)]) var expenses : FetchedResults<Expense>
    
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
                ScrollView(.vertical,showsIndicators: true) {
                    VStack {
                        HStack {
                            Text("Welcome.")
                                .font(.title)
                            Spacer()
                        }
                        
                        LazyVStack {
                            ForEach(expenses) { expens in
                                NavigationLink {
                                    EditExpenseView(expense: expens)
                                } label: {
                                    ExpenseDetail(amount: String(expens.amount), date: expens.date!, name: expens.name!, type: expens.type ?? "Transportation")
                                }
                                .contextMenu {
                                    Button {
                                        deleteExpense(expense: expens)
                                    } label: {
                                        Label("Delete", systemImage: "trash")
                                    }

                                }
                            }
                        }.transition(.move(edge: .leading))
                    }
                        
                    }
            .padding()
            .navigationTitle("Expenses")
        }
    }
    
    
    func deleteExpense(expense: Expense){
        withAnimation {
            managedObjectContext.delete(expense)
            
            do {
                try managedObjectContext.save()
                print("Data saved successfully")
            }catch {
                let nsError = error as NSError
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError)")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ExpenseView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ExpenseView()
    }
}
```

I've confirmed that the data is being fetched correctly and the views are being displayed. However, the .move transition animation doesn't seem to have any effect when new expenses are added or removed.

Comment: Moving the `.transition(move...` to the `NavigationLink` allows the delete to animate, but the add still just appears.

Comment: @vacawama i tried that but still not working even for delete

Comment: I wasn't involving Core Data, so that is definitely key to your problem.  I can get both the add and delete to animate if I wrap the add/delete code with `withAnimation` and move the `.transition(move...` to the `NavigationLink`.  Something about the `@FetchRequest` is different than just an array simulation.  Do you know if the ids of the `Expense`s are consistent from one fetch to the next?  Perhaps the fetch happens on another thread and that is fouling things up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok i find out @FetchRequest has it's own animation parameter so i changed my code like this and it works now :

```
import SwiftUI

struct ExpenseView: View {
    
    @AppStorage("darkMode") var isDarkMode = false
    
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
    
    @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [SortDescriptor(\.date,order: .reverse)],animation: .easeIn(duration: 0.8)) var expenses : FetchedResults<Expense>
    
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ScrollView(.vertical,showsIndicators: true) {
                VStack {
                    HStack {
                        Text("Welcome.")
                            .font(.title)
                        Spacer()
                    }
                    
                    LazyVStack {
                        ForEach(expenses) { expens in
                            NavigationLink {
                                EditExpenseView(expense: expens)
                            } label: {
                                ExpenseDetail(amount: String(expens.amount), date: expens.date!, name: expens.name!, type: expens.type ?? "Transportation")
                            }
                            .contextMenu {
                                Button {
                                    deleteExpense(expense: expens)
                                } label: {
                                    Label("Delete", systemImage: "trash")
                                }
                                
                            }
                            .transition(.slide)
                        }
                    }
                }
                
            }
            .padding()
            .navigationTitle("Expenses")
            .preferredColorScheme(isDarkMode ? .dark : .light)
        }
    }
    
    
    func deleteExpense(expense: Expense){
            managedObjectContext.delete(expense)
            
            do {
                try managedObjectContext.save()
                print("Data saved successfully")
            }catch {
                let nsError = error as NSError
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError)")
            }
        
        
    }
}

struct ExpenseView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ExpenseView()
    }
}
```